# How to use i386 Framework in x86_64 Swift Project

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, edsdk, canon-sdk

I created an Objective-C Framework for CanonEDSDK in which `EdsInitializeSDK` only support i386 architecture. I imported the framework into a Swift Project, but at the point of calling `EdsInitializeSDK()` I get the following error:

> "_EdsInitializeSDK", referenced from:
>         test.AppDelegate.applicationDidFinishLaunching (test.AppDelegate)(__ObjC.NSNotification) -> () in AppDelegate.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
>
> clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: You *cannot* use a 32-bit library from a 64-bit application.

Comment: So what would you suggest I do, @MartinR ?

Comment: You have to compile both as 32-bit or both as 64-bit. However – as far as I know – Swift requires 64-bit on OS X and on 64-bit iOS devices. Therefore the only chance would be to recompile the framework in 64-bit, otherwise you are out of luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described by @MartinR in the comments, Swift is 64 bits exclusively so all libraries used should be 64 bits. The EDSDK v3.2.1 for OSX does contain a 64bit version which you can use.

**Be aware that in this 64 bit version, operations on RAW files (saving as TIFF, but even reading info) can only be performed on files created by a limited set of new cameras :**

- EOS 5DS / EOS 5DS R /
- EOS REBEL T6s / EOS 760D / EOS 8000D /
- EOS REBEL T6i / EOS 750D / EOS Kiss X8i /
- EOS M3

**Operations on files from older cameras will attempt to dynamically load a 32-bit library, resulting in a runtime dynamic linking error!**

Comment: EDSDK is not 64-Bit compatible. You cannot call the EDSDK library from an application of 64bit.
For the camera connect functions and limited supported cameras for the image handling functions, we released a 64-bit library as a beta version on a trial basis.
Please note:Supported cameras are limited as below for the image hadling functions in 64-Bit module.
EOS 5DS / EOS 5DS R / EOS REBEL T6s / EOS 760D / EOS 8000D / EOS REBEL T6i / EOS 750D / EOS Kiss X8i / EOS M3


That is what I get in the doc file, and I use EOS 700D.

Any advice?

Comment: You can use the beta 64 bit sdk just fine, as long as you don't process any raw files (you can download them from  camera) with that app

Comment: I dont have the link to download the beta 64bit sdk, do you?

Comment: @KielSoft register with Canon's Digital Imaging Developer Programme (e.g. for Canon Europe use https://www.didp.canon-europa.com/) , and  then you should be able to find "Canon EOS Digital SDK ( EDSDK ) v3.2.1", file is called "EDSDKv0302-1M.zip"

Comment: NOTE: I notice that EDSDK_64 is not in the EDSDKv0302-1M.zip, but did find it at the 3.2 version EDSDKv0302M.zip.

Comment: Yea... I got the EDSDK_64 in the 3.0.2 package. thanks.